# Joining two tables on a timestamp in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to join two tables with the following query:

```
results = sqlContext.sql('SELECT * \
                          FROM airlines a \
                          INNER JOIN LATERAL ( \
                            SELECT * \
                            FROM weather w \
                            WHERE w.CALL_SIGN = a.ORIGIN  \
                              AND w.WEATHER_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN a.CRS_DEP_TIME - INTERVAL 15 MINUTES AND a.CRS_DEP_TIME + INTERVAL 15 MINUTES \
                            ORDER BY w.WEATHER_TIMESTAMP DESC \
                            LIMIT 1 ) \
                           ON a.ORIGIN = w.CALL_SIGN').cache()
```

I'm hitting an issue where I can't reference the `airlines` table in the inner-join. I tried adding the `LATERAL` keyword, hoping that Spark SQL supports it like Postgres to no avail. I'm not sure how to fix this query, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
'SELECT * \
                          FROM airlines a \
                          INNER JOIN ( \
                            SELECT * \
                            FROM weather w \
                            INNER JOIN airlines a
                            WHERE w.CALL_SIGN = a.ORIGIN  \
                              AND w.WEATHER_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN a.CRS_DEP_TIME - INTERVAL 15 MINUTES AND a.CRS_DEP_TIME + INTERVAL 15 MINUTES \
                            ORDER BY w.WEATHER_TIMESTAMP DESC \
                            LIMIT 1 ) x \
                           ON a.ORIGIN = x.CALL_SIGN'
```

Comment: It works if I really reduce the table, but times out with the full set.